# Lunar Turtlebot

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, ros

I just downloaded everything yesterday including WSL. I went on to download Lunar Loggerhead ROS only to eventually find out that I had some troubles installing turtlebot. After troubleshooting for a really long while, I gave up and went on to reformat my computer.

I did the process again and this time round I can't install indigo. Unable to fix as I have broken packages.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-indigo-desktop-full : Depends: ros-indigo-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-perception but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                           Depends: ros-indigo-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
toilet93@Bobby-RBS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who tried!